# Multiple Ajax.BeginForms and JQuery's .when() function

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I want to use [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to execute code after several Ajax.BeginForm forms on the page have completed submission.  Each of the forms can be submitted like so:

```
$('#formA').submit();
$('#formB').submit();
```

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9865124/2418006), I attempted the following:

```
$.when($('#formA').submit(), $('#formB').submit()).done(function(a1, a2)
{
   alert('Finished!');
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work - all forms return immediately and the "Finished!" dialogue box appears right away even though the ajax requests are still processing.  I know they're not finished processing b/c at this point none have made a callback to their AjaxOptions' onComplete function.  The example linked above uses an

```
return $.ajax({ });
```

block to designate the promise that the $.when() should wait for.  Presumably this is why my code does not work - as far as I know, I am not able to mandate a return on the Ajax.BeginForm element.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can use $.when() in conjunction with multiple Ajax.BeginForm asynchronous requests?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.submit()` is not an ajax request. Replace those with `.ajax(options)`. And forget about using the AjaxHelper.

Comment: So is that to say that .when cannot be used with Ajax.BeginForm?  Could you expand just a little on your comment? Thank you :D

Comment: In this case I don't see extension points for AjaxHelper to get promises to work. I avoid the AjaxHelper as it does little for me. Often I find I must do some customization to my AJAX calls which requires me to figure out how the helper works _OR_ I can spend that time to figure out how to make it work going the more platform-agnostic jQuery way. In other words 1) AjaxHelper knowledge does not easily transfer to non-MS tech. 2) There are many more AJAX examples to be found that does not use AjaxHelper.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! I will convert the helpers to a more generic form so I can use the complete ajax toolkit.